# Create variable names and assign values in R

Tags: r

My little example is as follows:

```
x = c(5,1,3)
y = c(-1,3,1)
X = cbind(x,y)
```

I want to achieve

```
x1 = X[1,]
y1 = X[2,]
z1 = X[3,]
```

in a loop. Then I try

```
x = c(5,1,3)
y = c(-1,3,1)
X = cbind(x,y)
nr = nrow(X)
nc = ncol(X)
for(i in nr){
    k = length(letters)
    get(paste0(letters[k-(nr-i)],1)) = X[i,]
}
```

But I get a error as

```
Error in get(paste0(letters[k - (nr - i)], 1)) <- X[i, ] :
could not find function "get<-"
```

How can fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be looking for `assign` instead of `get`. However, here is a way to do it without a loop.

```
list2env(setNames(asplit(X, 1), c('x1', 'y1', 'z1')), .GlobalEnv)

x1
# x  y 
# 5 -1 

y1
#x y 
#1 3 

z1
#x y 
#3 1
```

---

Using `assign` :

```
x = c(5,1,3)
y = c(-1,3,1)
X = cbind(x,y)
nr = nrow(X)
nc = ncol(X)
k = length(letters)

for(i in 1:nr){
  assign(paste0(letters[k-(nr-i)],1), X[i,])
}
```

Comment: Tks!  It works!  While, as you point out using `assign`, I change `get(paste0(letters[k-(nr-i)],1)) = X[i,]` as `assign(paste0(letters[k-(nr-i)],1), X[i,])` in my original code, and it still fails @ronak-shah@Ronak Shah

Comment: Wow, gorgeous! That's I want. Tks!@ronak-shah@Ronak Shah